# CoreData add object to to-many relashionship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

So I have `CustomEntity1` and `CustomEntity2` generated with mogenerator. `CustomEntity1` have a to-many relashionship with `CustomEntity2` and `CustomEntity2` have a reverse relashionship to-one with `CustomEntity1`.

My question is when I add some `CustomEntity2` to `CustomEntity1` by doing :

```
[CustomEntity1 addCustomEntity2Object:entity2FreshlyCreated]
```

Does it set the inverse relashionship ? Or do I have to do this too ?

```
CustomEntity2.parent = CustomEntity1;
```

Comment: did you try it, seems awfully simple to test out... actually your question almost contains the whole test.

Comment: lol sorry about the mana didn't even have time to edit it ! :p

Comment: And also I'm really new to core data been reading a lot about it to understand it better but I have no prior knowledge of database or anything, I started programming like a few months ago with obj-c for ios so I really don't know much and I don't know how to test it easily ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole reason Core Data asks you to indicate an inverse relationship for an object is so that it can update it automatically. The lines you posted are equivalent.